# ArrayList, java. Whats the difference between these two constructors

Tags: java

I'm kind of a newbie still in java, can you tell me whats the difference between these two constructors?

First:

```
public class Plan
{

   ArrayList<Point2D> points;

   public Plan(ArrayList<Ponto2D> points)
   {
       this.points = new Arraylist<Point2D>(points);
   }

}
```

and this :
second:

```
public class Plan
{

    public Plan(ArrayList<Point2D> lpoints)
    {
        points = new ArrayList<Point2D>();
        for(Point2D p : lpoints) point.add(p.clone());
    }

}
```

Comment: Please be careful with indent, your code is really hard to read

Comment: The first constructor takes a collection and assigns it to the `points` ArrayList, the second constructor takes a ArrayList, iterates through it, and adds to `points` after initializing `points`.

Comment: @Abdul, the first one doesn't assign the passed list, it copies the list.

Comment: @Abdul Also note the use of `Point2D.clone()` in the second example.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Ah ok, I just looked it up, and learned what a `shallow copy` is

Answer (score 5):

The first constructor is a *shallow copy*, the second one a *deep copy*.

Answer given by [S.Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10661/s-lott) for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy).

> Shallow copies duplicate as little as possible. A shallow copy of a
>   collection is a copy of the collection structure, not the elements.
>   With a shallow copy, two collections now share the individual
>   elements.
>
> Deep copies duplicate everything. A deep copy of a collection is two
>   collections with all of the elements in the original collection
>   duplicated.

Comment: I believe the first constructor is actually cloning the list, so not sharing the elements

Comment: @realUser404 It's a trap ! (:P) The first constructor clone the list, but share the same elements, the second one duplicate the elements thanks to `clone()`. You can take a look at the [OpenJDK implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java) of `ArrayList`, which use  `System.arraycopy(...)` behind the hood.

Answer (score 3):

```
this.points = new Arraylist<Point2D>(points);
```

This takes a whole collection and uses the collection to initlaize your `points` ArrayList.

```
for(Point2D p : lpoints) point.add(p.clone());
```

That has the same result but adds each element of the `lpoints`-collection one by one to your `points` list.

So for your usage, use the first possibility.

Comment: in second case, it adds a **copy** of the point2D, which is not quite the same

Answer (score 1):

in first case, the parameter ArrayList share the same points (p1.equals(p2) would be true, p1 == p2 would be true)
in the second case, they have different copy of the points (p1.equals(p2) would be true, but p1 == p2 would be false)

Answer (score 1):

In your first constructor you use the default Java Constructor for creating an ArrayList that takes a collection as it's argument.

([From Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html))

> **public ArrayList(Collection < ? extends E > c)**
>
> Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.

This is basically same as writing your own iterator (From your example).

```
public Plan(ArrayList<Point2D> lpoints) {
  points = new ArrayList<Point2D>();
  for(Point2D p : lpoints) 
      point.add(p.clone());
}
```

In this example however we use a method called .clone() because we don't want each object's shallow copy. We want to duplicate them.

[Edit]: Both the examples don't do the same thing. First one is a shallow copy and second one a deep copy.